# Do I need a pull-down resistor with this MOSFET-based motor driver?

Tags: dc-motor, driver, mosfet-driver, esp32, pulldown

I'm using the circuit in the picture to control a 12 V DC motor with an ESP32.

[image]

Do I need an extra pull-down resistor between the microcontroler pin and ground to avoid my pin floating and maybe activating my MOSFET?

Comment: But R2 is already a pull down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your existing gate drive circuit acts as a voltage divider decreasing the voltage on the MOSFET gate. Move the pull down resistor (R2) to the pin of the micro and the driver should work fine. The 1N4001 diode is not needed as the MOSFET is avalanche rated but it does not hurt anything. The motor connected to the 3V3 of the micro is a bad idea. You need to power it externally.

Comment: Thank you! Yes i forgot to mention that I am using an external voltage source for the motor. Do you mean I should exchange R1 and R2?

Comment: R1 is OK, Connect R2 between port pin D6 and ground.